# Parameters KFunction in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, events, function-parameter

I have a class that has the type parameter `KFunction<*>`
(It is understood that I will indicate the type of function that I want to work with in the future)

I want a class method to take the same parameters that KFunction has and call subscribers with those arguments. However, I don't know how to get the type of the function parameters. There are delegates in C #. How to do something like this in Kotlin?

My class:

```kt
class Event<Function: KFunction<*>> {
    val subscribers = mutableListOf<Function>()

    operator fun plus(increment: Function) {
        subscribers.add(increment)
    }

    // i want arguments as KFunction
    operator fun invoke(args: ???) {
        subscribers.forEach { it(args) }
    }
}

fun c(i: Int) {
    println("result of function c: $i")
}

fun main() {
    val event = Event<KFunction1<Int, Unit>>()
    event + ::c
    event(100) // passing arguments Int from KFunction1<Int, Unit>
}
```

Is there a way to implement my idea **exactly like this**?

Comment: You would need reflection to do this, and you would just have to make the invoke argument take varargs. There would be no type-checking at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only normal solution to problem is to accept only 1 abstract type of parameters.

```kt
class Event<ArgsT> {
    private val subscribers = mutableListOf<(ArgsT) -> Any>()

    operator fun plusAssign(increment: (ArgsT) -> Any) {
        subscribers.add(increment)
    }

    operator fun invoke(params: ArgsT) {
        subscribers.forEach { it(params) }
    }
}

fun c(i: Int, b: Int) {
    println(i + b)
}

data class Data(val i: Int, val b: Int)

fun main() {
    val event = Event<Data>()
    event += { (i, b) -> c(i, b) } // pass arguments using a lambda
    event(Data(2, 5))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it's implied that type, passed as a `Function : KFunction<*>` type parameter (`KFunction1<Int, Unit>` in this case) will have its own type parameters (`Int` and `Unit` in this case), and you want to declare `args` parameter as an uncertain amount of parameters with these exact types (excluding the last one, which represents type of function call result)?
I believe it's impossible.

The best you can do is to declare `args` as `vararg` with `Any?` type:

```kotlin
operator fun invoke(vararg args: Any?) = subscribers.forEach { it.call(*args) }
```